# How do I link or add a reference to specific lines of code of a file in the repository on GitLab?

Tags: github, gitlab

On GitHub, there's a very helpful feature which lets you add a few lines of code to your comment. However, the code itself is not pasted into the comment, but only a reference to a permalink of a file of the repository on GitHub is added. Rendered, it will look something like this:

[image]

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet#linking-to-code

To use this feature, I simply add `#L<linenumber-start>-L<linenumber-end>` to a permalink to a file. So the final link looks like this:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/blob/<commit>/<path>#L<linenumber-start>-L<linenumber-end>
```

However, if I try to use the syntax of this feature on GitLab with a permalink to a file in my GitLab repository, it doesn't work. What is the equivalent of this feature in GitLab? Or is it simply currently not possible?

Comment: You can link to a GitLab line with `#L<linenumber>`. Are you asking about the code embed?

Comment: @JakeLee Yes exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

In GitLab, you can comment directly on files changed in commits. If that commit is included in the MR, it will start a thread on the MR.

You can add comments by clicking the bubble next to any line of changes in a commit (or changes diff in an MR):

[image: changes comment]

and they will show up in the MR like so:

[image: commit comment]

---

The caveat, however, is that only files that are modified in at least one commit in the MR will show up in the MR UI. There is a workaround, but unfortunately, it's not as simple as just using a permalink.

If you want to make a comment and show code for some file that is not modified in the current MR, you will have to find a commit (preferably, the last commit modifying the file on the target branch) and add it to the MR, then make your comment.

You can do this by clicking the "add previously merged commit" button under the "commits" tab of the MR.

[image: add previously merged commit]

Then, if you add a comment on the commit that has been added, it will also show your comment as a thread in the MR with code preview. For example, this MR does not modify `.gitlab-ci.yml` but because I added the most recent commit for the file, comments I add on this commit will also show up in my MR, even though the file has not yet been modified in the present MR:

[image: unrelated change]

After your comment is made you can remove the commit from the MR the same way it was added, if you wish, and the comment will remain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sorry, that's not really helpful. Maybe there's a misunderstanding. GitHub also offers comments on code changes in a Pull Request. However, I'm talking about a different feature. You're talking about comments on Merge Requests. But imagine you don't even have a Merge Requests, yet, only a bug report issue thread and you want to reference code in a comment in said issue.